# In Android Compose, is it possible to always play an AnimatedVectorResource forwards?

Tags: android, kotlin, animation

Given this code sample from the docs, it's rather straightforward to have it play but to have the animation play again, it always plays in reverse.

Is there a way to trigger the animation to play again, but forwards?

```
val image = animatedVectorResource(drawableId)
var atEnd by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
Image(
    painter = image.painterFor(atEnd),
    contentDescription = "Your content description",
    modifier = Modifier.size(64.dp).clickable {
        atEnd = !atEnd
    }
)
```

It seems that you can only trigger the animation to play again, by toggling the `atEnd` variable, which is fine. BUT the problem is that the animation always plays in reverse. Is there a way around this?